# send request run before others in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await, wait

I have a function like this:

```
function sendRQ(url,filename){
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log('111');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.timeout = 2000;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    console.log('222');
    request.onload =  function (){
        console.log('333');
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log('444');
            var base = e.target.result;
            resolve(base);
            var arr = base.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
                bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
            while (n--) {
                u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
            }
            return new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime});
        };
        console.log('555');

    };
    request.send();
    console.log('666');

}).then(function (dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    console.log('777');
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime});
}).then(function (file) {
    console.log('888');

    return file;
});}
```

I set console.log in each level to get priority of running steps. But after echo "222" echo "666".
How can i fix it? I set promise , then but in doesn't work fine!

Comment: In which order you want it happen (I mean logging)

Comment: after console.log(222); i want wait for runnig request.onload and then others.. but it runs console.log(666)

Comment: when it returns file at the end, file is undefined

Comment: It's happening cause you make your request asyncrounous in this line: `request.open('GET', url, true);` when you pass 3rd argument as `true` - check this [async and sync requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) on MDN. But I don't recommend to use synchronous requests nowadays

Comment: Did the console log '333' and '444' if not then the request didn't succeed and it maybe faild.

Comment: "*`reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);`*" - something is wrong with the API you are using if it sends responses as data urls instead of files directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because you use async ajax 
At this line

```
request.onload =  function (){
```

You are just declaring a function that will be executed. when onload event is fired.

So it is normal to log 222 then declare the function then log 555 and after onload is emitted. then the function is excuted.

You can call resolve and path any data. this data will come at promise.then(data => {})
and reject data will come at promise.catch(err => {})

At your case you are resolving base
I think you meant to resolve File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime})

if you want to resolve new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime})

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log('444');
        var base = e.target.result;
        var arr = base.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        while (n--) {
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        resolve(new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime}));
    };
```

and remove this because you already resolved the file

```
then(function (dataurl) {
var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
}
console.log('777');
return new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime});
```

})

Comment: I should set wait in request.onload.. but when i set there, it doesn't work. I don't know how could set that!

Comment: For debugging like `request.onload` write a function for error `request.onerror = function(event) { console.log("Error"); reject(); };`; to make sure that the request didn't get error instead of success.